# Html/css: avoiding text button to be displayed under or above vertical scrollbar

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, scrollbar

Please take a look at the following snippet.
The purpose of this code is to display a dynamic folder list.

I have buttons inside some scrollable content. When button have a long text (see the third button), text "overflow" under the vertical scrollbar.

I try to contain the text into a Bootstrap panel-body which have natively 15px padding.
Unfortunatly, button text stay visible on the scrollbar area.

**Edit:** Long text crosses the vertical scrollbar. I try to avoid the superposition of text and scrollbar.

Looking for your suggestions. Many thanks.

Bootstrap 3.3.7, jQuery 2.1.4, jQuery-scrollbar 0.2.11

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.scrollbar-macosx').scrollbar();
});
```

```css
.cust-tree{
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.cust-tree button {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  padding-left: 25px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.cust-tree button::before {
  content: "";
  width: 18px;
  font-style: normal;
  height: 18px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-left: -25px;
  line-height: 18px;
}

.cust-tree.files .file {
  padding-left: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  line-height: 18px;
}


.group-list.scroll-wrapper {
    max-height:75px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.scrollbar/0.2.11/jquery.scrollbar.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script language="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.scrollbar/0.2.11/jquery.scrollbar.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>  
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div id="menu_grp" class="panel-body scrollbar-macosx group-list">
          <div class="panel-body cust-tree" id="divScriptMenu">
            <div><button type="button">TEST</button>
            </div>
            <div><button type="button">TEST</button>
            </div>
            <div><button type="button">TEST3TEST3TEST3TEST3TEST3TEST3TEST3TEST3TEST3TEST3</button>
            </div>
            <div><button type="button">TEST</button>
            </div>
            <div><button type="button">TEST</button>
            </div>
            <div><button type="button">TEST</button>
            </div>
            <div><button type="button">TEST</button>
            </div>
            <div><button type="button">TEST</button>
            </div>
            <div><button type="button">TEST</button>
            </div>
            <div><button type="button">TEST</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to remove the horizontal scroll? You just need to use;

```
overflow-x: hidden;
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.scrollbar-macosx').scrollbar();
});
```

```css
.cust-tree{
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}

.cust-tree button {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  padding-left: 25px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.cust-tree button::before {
  content: "";
  width: 18px;
  font-style: normal;
  height: 18px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-left: -25px;
  line-height: 18px;
}

.cust-tree.files .file {
  padding-left: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  line-height: 18px;
}


.group-list.scroll-wrapper {
    max-height:75px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.scrollbar/0.2.11/jquery.scrollbar.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script language="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.scrollbar/0.2.11/jquery.scrollbar.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>  
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div id="menu_grp" class="panel-body scrollbar-macosx group-list">
          <div class="panel-body cust-tree" id="divScriptMenu">
            <div><button type="button">TEST</button>
            </div>
            <div><button type="button">TEST</button>
            </div>
            <div><button type="button">TEST3TEST3TEST3TEST3TEST3TEST3TEST3TEST3TEST3TEST3</button>
            </div>
            <div><button type="button">TEST</button>
            </div>
            <div><button type="button">TEST</button>
            </div>
            <div><button type="button">TEST</button>
            </div>
            <div><button type="button">TEST</button>
            </div>
            <div><button type="button">TEST</button>
            </div>
            <div><button type="button">TEST</button>
            </div>
            <div><button type="button">TEST</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @C Prince: Hi,  I don't want to remove the horizontal scroll. Long text crosses the vertical scrollbar. I try to avoid that superposition.